# Spring @Transactional - Can I Override rollbackFor

Tags: java, spring, transactions, rollback

I am calling a service which has the following annotation:

```
@Transactional(rollbackFor=ExceptionA.class)
public void myMethodA(....) throws ExceptionA {
.
.
}
```

I am calling this method from an other method in another Spring Bean.

```
@Transactional(rollbackFor=ExceptionB.class)
public void mainEntryPointMethod(....) throws ExceptionB {
.
  try {
    myMethodA()
  }
  catch (ExceptionA exp) {
   .
  }


.
}
```

My problem is that if myMethodA throws an exception, my transaction (which is passed from mainEntryPointMethod -> myMethodA by default propagation) will be marked for rollback. Is there a way in which the 'rollbackFor' for the inner method can be overriden?

Thanks in advance
Chris

Comment: This probably depends on the underlying transaction coordinator, and how it handles nesting. My guess is that this won't work, though.

Answer (score 2):

Solution #1
You can specify that the method you are calling gets its own transaction.
You can do that by annotating the method.

```
 @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
```

That way if the method (myMethodA) is marked for roll back only that transaction will be rolled back and not the caller transaction.

That only works if you are allowed to let the called method manage its own transaction and don't want to roll back the caller transaction.

Solution #2
Maybe you can try to subclass and change the transactional annotation attributes.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Alfredo. Well, that is one possibility, however I would like to do it without modifying the service method. I would like to leave the called method (myMethodA) with the default propagation (required) such that if it is called from somewhere else, it will rollback in case of error. I want it to behave differently when I call it from 'mainEntryPointMethod'. (always if this is possible).